# SQL nvarchar order

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a problem with my table in my database.

Here's the problem:

Why is `'BP99999'` is greater than `'BP100000'` ?

Whenever I query where this column is ordered by `DESC` it takes `'BP99999'` as the first row instead of the `'BP100000'`

Additional info: my column type is `nvarchar`

Do you have any suggestions for this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Because it's a **string**, the `9` after the `BP` is **greater** than the `1` after the `BP` prefix .... because it's a **string** it doesn't look at numerical values - it just compares the **STRING** ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presently the 9 after the BP is greater than 1 resulting in the problem which you are facing.

The possible solution is that you need to take out the first 2 characters out of your column value and then do the sorting on the integer value.

You may try something like this:

```
SELECT [BProject_ID] 
FROM [Workload].[dbo].[Bending_Projects] 
ORDER BY RIGHT([BProject_ID], LEN([BProject_ID]) - 2)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, i tried using your query but i got an error
"Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int."
here is my query:

`SELECT [BProject_ID]
FROM [Workload].[dbo].[Bending_Projects]
ORDER BY CAST(ISNULL(NULLIF(ISNUMERIC([BProject_ID]),0),2147888647) as INT)`

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY RIGHT([BProject_ID], LEN([BProject_ID]) - 2)
```

Or simpler

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING([BProject_ID],2,8000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other's answer you only need to collect the number to ordering

```
ORDER BY RIGHT(BP_ID, (CHAR_LENGTH(BP_ID)) - 2 )
```

but you still need to convert string into integer

```
ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(BP_ID, (CHAR_LENGTH(BP_ID)) - 2 ) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Note : I am use MySQL